# ionic serve running local serve,But an error occurred .ERROR:no such file or directory, open 'E:\xxx\www\index.html

Tags: ionic2

Reference here

> E:\code>ionic start test2 --v2 Creating Ionic app in folder
>   E:\code\test2 based on tabs project Downloading:
>   `https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.zip`
>   [=============================]  100%  0.0s Downloading:
>   `https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter- tabs/archive/master.zip`
>   [=============================]  100%  0.0s Installing npm packages...
>
> Adding initial native plugins [=============================]  100% 
>   0.0s
>
> Saving your Ionic app state of platforms and plugins Saved platform
>   Saved plugins Saved package.json
>
> ♬ ♫ ♬ ♫  Your Ionic app is ready to go! ♬ ♫ ♬ ♫
>
> Some helpful tips:
>
> Run your app in the browser (great for initial development):   ionic
>   serve
>
> Run on a device or simulator:   ionic run ios[android,browser]
>
> Test and share your app on device with Ionic View:
>   `http://view.ionic.io`
>
> Build better Enterprise apps with expert Ionic support:
>   `http://ionic.io/enterprise`
>
> New! Add push notifications, live app updates, and more with Ionic
>   Cloud!   `https://apps.ionic.io/signup`
>
> New to Ionic? Get started here:
>   `http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting- starte d`
>
> E:\code\test2>ionic serve Running live reload server:
>   `http://192.168.133.113:35729` Watching: www/**/*, !www/lib/***/,
>   !www/**/*.map √ Running dev server:  `http://192.168.160.113:8100` Ionic
>   server commands, enter:   restart or r to restart the client app from
>   the root   goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given
>   url   consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
>   serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output   quit or q to
>   shutdown the server and exit
>
> ionic $

```
E:\code\test2>ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 3.4.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v6.11.0
```

I need your help!
 Thanks in advance and sorry for my English

Comment: My solution for update ionic2 to 2.2.1 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have same issue created

solution for

```
plz edit to confing.xml file

<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```